# Getting unknown cert error when creating ArgoCD Application

Tags: argocd, gitops

I setup a new Argo Setup on our Kubernetes Cluster and playing around with manual Application creation and it throwed the below error

> Unable to create application: application spec for app-name is
> invalid: InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: repositories not
> accessible: &Repository{Repo: "https://ourlocalgit.repo", Type: "",
> Name: "", Project: ""}: repo client error while testing repository:
> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository
> connectivity: Get
> "https://ourlocalgit.repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack": x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority

What am I missing here? Since its first time I am setting it up, need some advice.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to configure the TLS certificate for your git service.

Docs are here: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/private-repositories/#self-signed-untrusted-tls-certificates